# Acceso a carpeta en red pasandole en la url las credenciales

Tags: java

Buenas, tengo un sistema hecho en Java, en donde tengo una clase que busca un numero de cédula particular en la carpeta compartida de cédulas. Para evitar el trabajo de crear una unidad de red lo que hago es acceder a ella como **file://ur/carpetaCompartida**, lo hago de la siguiente manera:

```
String NomFichero = "file://190.0.0.100/Cedulas/" + tbDocumento.getValueAt(tbDocumento.getSelectedRow(), 1);
if(java.awt.Desktop.isDesktopSupported()) {
    try {
        Desktop dk = Desktop.getDesktop();
        dk.browse(new URI(NomFichero+".pdf"));
    }
    catch(Exception e1) {
        try {
            Desktop dk = Desktop.getDesktop();
            dk.browse(new URI(NomFichero+".jpg"));
        }
        catch(Exception e2) {    
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"ERROR: "+ e2.getMessage());
        }            
    }                                   
}
```

Lo que hace es, va recorriendo toda la carpeta buscando una que tenga el mismo nombre y cuando lo encuentra abre la imagen.
Bueno, funciona sin problema, para que tenga accedo a esa carpeta compratida, manualmente debo entrar en cada pc, acceder a dicha carpeta e introducir las credenciales, marcando que queden registradas para esa pc. Ese paso me quiero evitar, pasando las credenciales via url(justamente eso quiero saber si es posible) en esta línea: **"file://190.0.0.100/Cedulas/"**, o ver otra forma para pasar las credenciales.

Comment: que sistema operativo usas? o  buscas una solución multiplataforma?

Comment: tal vez te convenga montar unidades de red en windows se hace algo como `net use w: \\server\share /user:test testpassword` desde Java podrías ejecutar el comando con un runtime.exec